# TeamCity automated email notifier

Tags: git, teamcity

TeamCity 9.0 has "All Users" group that contains all TeamCity users. The default setting for this group is to be notified when builds with my changes fail (ignore failure not caused by my changes).

[image: Default notification settings for All Users]

Does this mean that anyone that wants to be notified by TeamCity MUST have an account setup? I would prefer not to do that for all the developers in our company. Can't the emails be sent automatically to the Git user that breaks the build based on their Git profile? This would save time managing user accounts.

Answer (score 2):

TeamCity does not infer who "breaks" the build. I wrote an app to inspect the last committer who broke the build, and text-to-speech blamed them on company speakers :) You have to setup the accounts for the users or simply add a catch-all email to development@yourcompany.com.

Comment: I figured since with Git you set your user.name and user.email this would be enough for TeamCity to know who broke the build. Therefore, from your email attached to your commit, TeamCity could send the automated emails, but I guess this feature isn't available.